# How to download jQuery plugins when repository down?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

This might not be the right place to ask it, but when I open the [jQuery plugin repository](http://plugins.jquery.com/), I get this message:

> We've been looking to provide a higher-quality, spam-free experience
>   at the plugins site for some time, and a major error on our part
>   forced us to shut down the current site before we could put the new
>   one in place. We are developing a new site, and you can follow along
>   with its development on GitHub. For more information about this
>   transition, including steps you can take as a plugin author to
>   prepare, please read our post about what's going on.

There are many plugins that can only be downloaded from the repository. Is there a workaround?

I've been seeing this message for +1 month now and it is driving me **crazy**!

<sub>As a sidenote: I'm searching for http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/.</sub>

Comment: Did you try [the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: Yep... no-one there... "3 hours later…" :P

Comment: Why should he chat if he got a question (thats what SO is for right?)

Comment: @ErikDekker, there is a wealth of documentation about precisely which questions are on-topic for SO, and if you find yourself starting your question with "This might not be the right place to ask it", then usually trying the chat first can be a good idea. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://blog.jquery.com/2011/12/08/what-is-happening-to-the-jquery-plugins-site/

> ### In The Interim
>
> We recognize that the old site was still
>   serving as an regular resource for a lot of people, especially newer
>   jQuery users, who simply valued the existence of a central browsing
>   location, despite its flaws. Though many experienced users had moved
>   on to other sites, or relied on relationships with trusted authors and
>   word of mouth, these can take time to develop. Until we’re able
>   to launch the new system, we’re happy to direct you to several
>   other directories and people who can help pick up the slack:
>
> [jQuery List](http://jquerylist.com)
>
> [jQuery Style](http://jquerystyle.com)
>
> [Mike Alsup](http://jquery.malsup.com/)
>
> [Ben Alman](http://github.com/cowboy)
>
> [Matteo Bicocchi](http://pupunzi.com/#mb.components/components.html)
>
> [Jörn Zaefferer](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/)
>
> If, in the process of searching these or
>   any other directories, you are directed back to the current site at
>   plugins.jquery.com, typically a quick search for the author’s
>   name and the plugin name will yield an alternative site where it was
>   hosted. In addition, DailyJS just did
>   a useful roundup of alternatives that goes into more detail.

The old archive can be accessed by: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/

Comment: @bazmegakapa can you reinstate the links, unless they're no longer available!

Answer (score 2):

TouchSwipe is hosted on Github if you still need it:
https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin

Comment: Waaaaaaah thanks a million! I'll nominate you for some digital beer!

Comment: Another option was/is that because the demos (e.g. http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/demo/basics_4.php) still work off of the skinkers site if you look at the page source you can copy/paste from their JavaScript directly - http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/demo/js/jquery.touchSwipe-1.2.5.js

Answer (score 0):

I simply started googling the plugins I was looking for. It works 99% of the time. In most cases, much better than the jQuery plugin repository too, because the plugins there were usually outdated or lacked updated links to documentation, homepage etc.

I'd recommand simply adding jquery plugin to your search.

```
swipe jquery plugin 
carousel jquery plugin
```

And so on.

Comment: Didn't really help: http://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&q=touchswipe+jquery+plugin&pbx=1&oq=touchswipe+jquery+plugin&aq=f&aqi=g-s1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=558l5318l0l5806l6l5l0l0l0l0l260l601l1.2.1l5l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=a4772a362b65a33d&ion=1&biw=1680&bih=946

Comment: See first result: http://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&q=swipe+jquery+plugin&pbx=1&oq=swipe+jquery+plugin&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=5280l5910l0l6008l5l5l0l0l0l4l214l723l0.3.1l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=6d00cd595fd04450&biw=1920&bih=958&ion=1

Comment: Hahaha is a diffent plugin :D I'm searching for apples, you just gave me a search for oranges. But their both fruit and tasty!

Comment: @OptimusCrime: the first result is the not-working-in-development-site what this question is about: http://screencast.com/t/5wWDLGoI

Comment: Inspect the sourcecode. This took me 1 minute. http://www.ryanscherf.net/demos/swipe/

Comment: @OptimusCrime swipe != touchSwipe

Comment: In what way? This was made for tablets. I've used it myself. Works like a charm.